# Study convergence in distribution of $T_{n}(x)=\frac{|x|^{\frac{1}{n}-1}}{2n}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, distribution-theory

I have a problems in distribution theory but I don't know if my step correct!
Study the convergent of $T_{n}$ in $D'(\mathbb{R})$
Where :

$$T_{n}(x)=\frac{|x|^{\frac{1}{n}-1}}{2n}$$
$$k\in \mathbb{N}~,~ x\in \mathbb{R^{*}}$$
My try :
Its clearly that : $T_{n}\in L^{1}_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb{R^{*}})$ so :
$\langle T_{n} ,\varphi \rangle =\int_{\mathbb{R}}T_{n}(x)\varphi(x)dx$
And we have $\varphi\in D'(\mathbb{R})\implies \exists a>0 ~\text{supp}\varphi \subset [a,a]$ so :
$\langle T_{n} ,\varphi \rangle =\int_{|x|≤a}T_{n}(x)\varphi(x)dx≤\frac{a^{\frac{1}{n}-1}}{2n}\int_{|x|≤a}\varphi (x)dx$ and this go to $0$ because $\int_{|x|≤a}\varphi (x)dx<\infty $

Also here we say convergence in
$D'(\mathbb{R^{*}}) ~\text{or} ~D'(\mathbb{R})$ ? Also $\varphi \in D(\mathbb{R}) ~\text{or}~D(\mathbb{R^{*}})$

In finally thank you to every teachers see my problems

I'm greatful

---

Thanks!

Comment: What is $\mathbb R^*$?

Answer (score 1):

I get that $T_n \to \delta$:
$$
\left< T_{n}, \varphi \right>
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{|x|^{\frac{1}{n}-1}}{2n} \, \varphi(x) \, dx
= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{\frac{1}{n}-1}}{2n} \, (\varphi(x) + \varphi(-x)) \, dx
= \{ x = y^n \} \\
= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\varphi(y^n) + \varphi(-y^n)}{2} \, dy
= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\varphi(y^n) + \varphi(-y^n)}{2} \, dy
+ \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\varphi(y^n) + \varphi(-y^n)}{2} \, dy \\
\to \int_{0}^{1} \varphi(0) \, dy
+ \int_{1}^{\infty} \underbrace{\varphi(\infty)}_{=0} \, dy
= \varphi(0)
= \left< \delta, \varphi \right>
.
$$
This is a bit sloppy. Some more work might be needed to justify the limits better.